# How to save txt File created by BCP command on different server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created text file using following command on the server where database resides

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 
RECONFIGURE EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 
RECONFIGURE EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT top 10 macnum, Cus_name,Cus_Email FROM [VBOS_TSP].[dbo].[Cust_file]" queryout "d:\creatFile.txt" -T -c'
```

But I need to create that text file on another machine. As I don't want to save that text file on production. Please suggest me other way so that by passing Path and/or passing credentials of a particular server. How to generate that file on other server?

Comment: Have you considered mapped drives?

Comment: Can you explain more briefly, Dan??

Answer (score 1):

The path in the other machine should be shared path and accessible from this machine and should have full permissions for the folder to read/write.

I worked on similar scenario and below code format works for me. Try it once after give permissions

```
@LV_FILE_PATH='\\192.168.1.105\Folder\creatFile.txt'
@LV_SQLTXT='"SELECT top 10 macnum, Cus_name,Cus_Email FROM [VBOS_TSP].[dbo].[Cust_file]"'

SET @LV_CMDTXT =  'BCP ' + @LV_SQLTXT + ' QUERYOUT "' + @LV_FILE_PATH + '" -c -U -T -S -r\n'
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @LV_CMDTXT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an unc path for queryout at bcp. You're only solution is to export it on the current machine and copy it afterwards.

Another idea is to run bcp on the remote maschine and connect to your datastore to export the data by using the parameter -S.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Ionic, I tried it. But it still creates that text file on the server where database resides....

Comment: Btw. the idea of mapped drives could probably work too. But I'm not quite sure. You can map a unc path to a local drive and try to write to this drive.

Comment: Depends on the way you executes bcp. You can run sqlcmd on the remote machine run bcp on this machine. Did you use the -S parameter?

Btw. another idea is to export data with powershell which is also a good solution if you need to copy your data.

Comment: No i didn't use -s parameter. Ok I will try it.

Comment: A great documentation about bcp can be retrieved here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

There you'll find some information about -S too.

Comment: Oh, Thank's Ionic...I will refer it.